# Dwarven civil disobedience

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I reclaimed a fortress and created tasks for my dwarves(workshop orders, digging), but they're just standing around the wagon. What's going on?

Comment: Brilliant title

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to reclaim items, workshops, etc. As specified in [this](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Reclaim_fortress_mode#How_to_reclaim_a_fortress) wiki article.